# Is it ok that my furnace uses the air conditioner for dehumidification?

Tags: dehumidifier, carrier

I have a Carrier 59mn7 furnace with an Infinity Thermo.  The a/c condenser is a Ruud.  The system does not have a dehumidifier installed--it is using the a/c during the dehumidifying function.

Is this OK or should I disable the dehumidifier function?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Air conditioners cool the air inside your house and also lower the humidity. There are thermostats that are sensitive to humidity,the dehumidifying function, and will turn on the AC just to reduce humidity. If your system can maintain a RH of 40 to 60% without over cooling, then leave it as it is. If the RH is over 60% with normal cooling, You'd be better off getting a dehumidifier installed since it will be much cheaper to run than your AC unit.